# Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Is it safe to say "if $u \in U, v \in V \setminus U$, then $u+v \notin U$, but $u+v \in V$?"

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it safe to say "if $u \in U, v \in V \setminus U$, then $u+v \notin U$, but $u+v \in V$?"

The fact "$u+v \in V$" is obvious, but I am not quite sure about "$u+v \notin U$."

This is unclear to me because subspace $U$ must hold the additivity, so "if $u,v \in U$, then $u+v \in U$."

But, this doesn't mean "if $u \in U$ and $v \notin U$, then $u+v \notin U$," which is just explained as it is obvious in my textbook.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. For if $u + v \in U$, then the same would be true of $u + v + (-u)$.

Comment: Expanding Theo's argument a bit further: suppose we had $u + v \in U.$ By the additive inverse property of vector spaces, we know $-u \in U,$ and by closure under addition we know $u + v + (-u) \in U.$ By the associative property (another vector space axiom) and the definition of the additive inverse we then have $v \in U,$ but this contradicts $v \in V \setminus U,$ so we must have $u + v \notin U.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $u+v\in U.$ Then $(u+v)-u\in U$ since $u+v\in U$ and $-u\in U.$ Can you do the rest?